# PIC16F57 External RC Oscillator oscillates but does not supply clock or appear on OSC2 pin

Tags: pic

using 22pf cap and 10K resistor connected to OSC1 pin.  Config word set to 0xFB.  OSC1 trace shows expected 1MHz sawtooth, but no activity on OSC2 and no clock to processor.  Happens on at least 3 chips.  External XTAL (Config set to 0xF9) works fine.

Comment: How is the reset handled? Or the power supply? Does power supply rise fast enough so there is enough supply voltage when the chip comes out of reset?

Comment: Did you purchase them from an authorized distributor?  There are clones of the PIC16F57 on the market which may not be 100% compatible, especially with a rarely used function like RC clock f/4 output. Of course they should not be marked with the Microchip logo but it is possible.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, personal tutorial service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: That's really strange, since you see the sawtooth the oscillator itself is working and IIRC there's nothing extra to do to see the fosc/4 on OSC2. I'd check if bypass is correct and similar issue (also try manually resetting it, the PIC POR is not infallible). The fuse word seems fine to me

Comment: Thanks for all the thoughtful answers and comments.  I tried a PIC12F509, and I can change from the internal RC oscillator to an external RC oscillator with no problems.  I have a few more Microchip types, so I'll try them too.  All of my PIC chips were bought directly from Mircochip several years ago, so they are genuine.  I'll try to reset the PIC16F57's and double check the RESET.

Comment: Justme and Lorenzo Marcantonio:  Yup, you guys are right.  I had my RESET gated incorrectly,  THANKS!